# Add a Button dynamically to a LinearLayout in Android

Tags: java, android, button, dynamic

I am working on a project that needs to add buttons dynamically. But whenever I run my application the application force closes. I've learned that the problem is when I try to add buttons.

```
package com.Feras.TestProject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class TestProject extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AddAll();
    // Set Text for the button in the Old Testament



}
public void AddAll() {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    Button btn = new Button(this); 
    btn.setText("MyButton"); 
    linearLayout.addView(btn); 


    }
}
```

Comment: Please use 'adb logcat' to get a proper stacktrace of the application (it resides in the platform-tools folder in installed Android SDk).

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
linearLayout.addView(
                     btn, 
                     new LayoutParams(
                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                     );
```

Comment: I would inflate, I dont think adding from code is the best practice

Answer (score 1):

there will only occure an error if linearLayout is null, ensure that layout1 is a valid Item of R.layout.main

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your custom activity class:

```
this.addContentView(call,
    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```