# Is both Static and Dynamic Layout Possible?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an XML layout having a single TextView

Now I want to add 50 buttons which I want to add dynamically in my java file !.

Is it possible to add attributes to an XML file via java code ?? 
Or can an activity have 2 layouts at a time ??

for eg,

```
public class Options extends Activity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.options);
    Button but=new Button(this);
    but.setText("Wassup");
    // How do I add this button to the layout ?
}

}
```

Comment: see this...

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631913/add-a-button-dynamically-to-a-linearlayout-in-android

may be a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to add attributes to an XML file via java code ??

No, but you can add properties to `Views` and `Layouts` as you are doing with `setText()`. `resource` files themselves cannot be changed after compiled.

> Or can an activity have 2 layouts at a time ??

The simple answer is no but you can `inflate` another layout and add it to the current layout.

**Example of what you can do to add a `Button`**

Inflate your root `layout` and add the `Buttons` to it with `addView()`. Something like

```
Layoutinflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_file);
Button but=new Button(this);
but.setText("Wassup");
// How do I add this button to the layout ?
ll.addView(but);
```

[LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Or if you want to add it to a `layout` in the current file you can just use `findViewById()` and use `addView()` on that to add your `Buttons` to.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have an xml layout as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@id/mainlayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In your java code after  setContentView(R.layout.options); you can do the following:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
Button button=new Button(this);
linearLayout.addView(button);
```

Now you can add as many buttons you like into the linear layout as seen above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. After `setContentView(R.layout.options);` get your buttons container with `findViewById`(). You will have a reference to a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout or something else. After that use Layout inflater and programmatically you can add other layouts or components.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @MarkBasler I wrote in my profile: I don't give fish, I am whiling to teach a fishing little. I know that would be apreciated, but use his brain a little and the Google. Ofc if he is whiling to pay I will write code :)

Comment: Notice the accepted answer had an example.  It doesn't need to be exactly what they need.

Comment: oh, yes, usually  Iam telling what to do, others read that give code they answer is accepted and up-voted and mine, not always, who cares? :)

Comment: Helping others regardless of what you get is always the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

just use layout.addView() where layout is a ViewGroup that you get by calling findViewById(R.id.layoutId)