# Android: Adding layout to a different activity's layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently trying to add a layout (box.xml) to my main layout (activity_main.xml) from a different activity, but having trouble correctly doing this. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

(Note: removed params for simplicity)

> activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>

            <!--include layout="@layout/box"-->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

> box.xml

```
<TableLayout>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView/>
        <ImageView/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView/>
        <Button/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

> CreateNewBoxActivity.java

(Note: My MainActivity.java calls startActivity(new Intent(this, CreateNewBoxActivity.class)))

```
public class CreateNewBoxActivity extends Activity {

   private ImageButton  mFinish;
   ...

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_newBox);

      mFinish = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_finish);

      mFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View view)
         {

            //add box.xml where <include layout> is located in activity_main.xml

            finish(); //close this activity and back to main activity to see 
                      //added box layout
         }
      });
      ...

   }
}
```

Thanks for any help on how to add this layout! Not sure the best way to tackle this.

Comment: Do you **have** to do it programmatically or can you add it to your xml?

Comment: Why not add it in the xml and toggle visibility?

Comment: @codeMagic: I would like to add the boxes programmatically to make adding the boxes dynamic for better user control.  I don't want the boxes there at all unless the user wants to create a new one.

Comment: @FD: I was considering using ViewStub to maybe set a limit to how many boxes a user can add, but I was having trouble finding main_activity.xml ViewStub from my CreateNewBoxActivity since my setContentView is set to R.layout.activity_newBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to inflate `box.xml`. Make sure you have an `id` for the `LinearLayout` that you want to add the `box.xml` to. Inflate that `layout` with something like

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llId);
```

then you can use [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)) to add the box `layout` to your `LinearLayout`.

[See this answer for a more detailed example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453341/is-both-static-and-dynamic-layout-possible/17453444#17453444)

**Edit**

After further discussion, the OP wants to add certain elements from the `layout` in the second `Activity` to the `layout` used in the first `Activity`. This would be accomplished easier by using `startActivityForResult()` and passing back the data to the first `Activity`.

Then, in `onActivityResult()` in the first `Activity` the appropriate `layout` can be added to the original `layout` using the previously mentioned approach (inflating and calling `addView()`).

How to handle the data and  what needs to be added depends completely on how this is handled by the dev. Data could be added to a model class from the second `Activity` then checked and added in `onActivityResult()` or this same method could check for `Intent` data passed back through `setResult()`.

[Intent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) contains an example and the method needed to pass data back.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558689/back-to-previous-activity-with-intent/20558774#20558774) has a brief example of using `startActivityForResult()` and passing back `Intent` data.

Comment: When I inflate my box.xml, what do I pass in for the ViewGroup parameter? TableLayout box = (TableLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.box, ? );

Comment: Either `null` or the `ViewGroup` to attach it to. I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026926/making-sense-of-layoutinflater) explains it fairly well.

Comment: I'm getting a nullpointerException on my LinearLayout, is this because that layout is located in my activity_main.xml? I was able to inflate my box.xml (by using debugger) but can't seem to add that view to my linearlayout

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I thought you were trying to do it in the `Activity` that had `main` as its `layout`. You want to put it in a `layout` that isn't inflated for that `Activity`??? That's backwards and won't work.

Comment: Sorry if I made this confusing :( Yea I basically wanted to add the box.xml to the LinearLayout in activity_main.xml while in the activity CreateNewBoxActivity that had a different layout for its setContentView() call.

Comment: No, that's backwards. Make `activity_main` the `layout` with `setContentView()` then allow the user to add the `box` layout to it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47458/discussion-between-a-donahue-and-codemagic)